# how to invoke user's (non-outlook) email application from .NET program

Tags: c#, .net, email

My C# application needs to email problem reports from the user's machine to a support tech.  There is no common SMTP server available, so I don't think I can use System.Net.Mail;  instead the message must be sent using the user's own email program and account.  I could use office automation to launch outlook and compose a message.  But what if the user is not using outlook?  Is there any more general mechanism that is supported by multiple email clients?  Or is there a library that knows how to detect and invoke various clients?

EDIT: as this for submitting problem reports, I need to include attachments or (at worst) a long message body...

Comment: Keep in mind, your approach will start an email in the user's client but they will still have to manually send the email.

Comment: @JeffH -- I'm fine with that (in fact I prefer it) but thanks for mentioning it; there are clearly other situations where it would be a problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Process.Start("mailto:hurr@durr.com");
```

The [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx) method hands off to the operating system the responsibility of executing a particular instruction.  Windows will recognize the [mailto](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_mailto) scheme and lauch the appropriate mail client.  This is configured using [Default Programs](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/332003).

Comment: But what about composing the message?

Comment: @Eric: See my answer... The body is problematic, but subject, cc, and bcc are pretty easy.

Comment: @eric The `mailto` scheme is a standard URI and has a number of different query/fragment parts that you can use to configure the email.  Check out the RFC for more info:  http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2368

Comment: @eric also if you have more specific requirements (like automatically sending the email--a bad requirement imho) you'll have to use automation for the particular email client.  That's a bit more heavy lifting than Process.Start can handle.

Answer (score 4):

If you want this to work with any email applications, you probably need to just use `Process.Start` with a `mailto:` URL defined with a short body and subject.

This should work, in a general purpose case:

```
Process.Start(@"mailto:your@email.com?cc=other@email.com&bcc=stillanother@email.com&subject=Bug Report&body=This may or may not show up.");
```

However, the body tag is often ignored by mail clients.  Unfortunately, there is no general purpose way to get everything in a `mailto:` .

Answer (score 2):

for new line body use **%0A** and for New Paragraph use **%0A%0A**.