# Capture email sent with outlook from browser

Tags: c#, web-services, outlook, ms-office

I want to be able to capture a email that gets sent via outlook and initiated from a browser mailto link so that I can save a copy back to my web application.

I can get buy with c#, I am currently building a web application using c# but would ideally like it to be possible to do from a php application without needing to rely on a specific web browser.

So far it seems that my best option will be to build an add-in for outlook that can detect the relevant flag and save a copy of the email once sent back to the application via a webservice connection.

I don't have a great deal of experience dealing with Office add-ins and am interested to know if I can pass custom information through the mailto link and then read it using the add-in when new message is started.

I also seem to have an issue where I don't have access to certain information while the email is being composed and don't have a reliable way to match that particular in-composition email to the email that gets saved in outbox then moved to inbox.

I am working with Visual Studio 2010 and Office 2010 at the moment.

Comment: read this post it has a link to a wrapper if it helps

Comment: oh sorry it could not be posted that was funny http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118848/how-to-invoke-users-non-outlook-email-application-from-net-program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this normally because when you supply a mailto link you're actually requesting the default mail program on the user's computer to send the mail. Because you don't know (and shouldn't be willing to know) which program this is you have no control over the mail sent.

One solution would be to have a special page in you web application in which your user can compose it's email. After composing you could supply this format to the SMTP server for delivery and you could store it wherever in your webapp you like. The point here is that you want to stay in control and having a mailto link will send the control over sending an email to a different program.

Comment: :) Sounds great to me.. the issue I have is the people that insist they want to use outlook to send emails.

Comment: I know these kinds of requirements :), maybe you can do something with integrating to the mailserver? So you can get all the sent mails from the mailserver after they're sent.